# Spring Security bypass URL or Filter

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that is only exposing a REST API. I need to secure it and I'm using a token-based approach ― specifically JWT.

So far, this is what I have implemented:

```
//
// The Spring Security configuration class
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/api/login", "/api/logout").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }
}
```

---

```
//
// The JWT filter class to check for the token in the HTTP request (headers)
public final class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Override
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws
      IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    final String header = req.getHeader("Authorization");

    logger.debug("{} {}", req.getMethod(), req.getRequestURI());
    if ((null == header) || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      logger.debug("Missing or invalid Authorization header");
    }
    try {
      // Check the token here; the implementation is not relevant here
      /*SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
          .setAuthentication(manager.authenticate(new JwtToken(JWTParser.parse(header.substring(7)))));*/
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (final AuthenticationException e) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      // Do some other stuff here
    } catch (final ParseException e) { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

The issue is that the filter executes correctly for every single URI, but I want to be able to exclude some endpoints from the same set. My API is placed in this context `/api/*` and I want to exclude, for instance, `/api/login` and `/api/logout`.

**NOTE:** My Spring Boot `application.yml` file doesn't have settings to enable/modify any security-related features.

Comment: You added your custom filter that does the token verification _before_ the authorization filter supplied by spring security. Was that your intention? Now  login hits your filter before it has a chance to hit your authentication filter. I would expect token verification filters only after the authentication filter because you probably have no security context before your authorization filter is executed (unless you have another auth filter in front of your jwt filter which you didn't share here).

Comment: `login` is a `POST` operation where the authentication is happening (skip this now if it's a good or bad; I know it's bad to implement it that way in REST). I just want to be able to hit `login` and `logout` without getting into the filter that checks for the token. Everything else is blocked by default.

Comment: Do you want it to hit your authentication filter? If yes, move your jwt filter after the authentication filter and keep your permit all, that should work.

Comment: So, what do I need to modify in the piece of code that is there in the answer. The authentication is taking place in an endpoint (`login`), there is no authentication filter.

Comment: .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) --> .addFilterAfter(new JwtFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Filters will be executed for all the endpoints that are configured through HttpSecurity. If you do not want filters to be applied for certain endpoints, include them in a method that configures WebSecurity. For example,

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/api/login", "/api/logout");
}
```

Please read [this post](http://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll) for more details.

Comment: Just can't manage to make this work. I only see this solution, but it does not work at all.

Comment: this doesn't work when a custom filter is added.

Answer (score 1):

```
In Spring Boot, you can use annotations to control the execution of filters. You can achieve this using the @ConditionalOnProperty annotation to conditionally enable or disable a filter based on a specific property value.


In your application.properties or application.yml file, set the value of the property custom.filter.enabled to control whether the filter should be enabled or skipped
   

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "custom.filter.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyCustomFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Initialization logic if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Filter logic
        // You can skip/filter out certain requests here if needed
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup logic if needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to disable the whole security configuration by using

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("api/auth/signup");
}
```

or by using spring's 6.0.0+

```
public HttpSecurity securityMatchers(Customizer<RequestMatcherConfigurer> requestMatcherCustomizer) {
    requestMatcherCustomizer.customize(this.requestMatcherConfigurer);
    return HttpSecurity.this;
}
```

these options also affect all the stuff that SecurityFilterChain does and might have some unexpected side-effects like disabled CORS which is strongly recommended to use.

As an option you can make your JwtFilter to be a child of

```
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
```

which one has a protected method

```
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter#shouldNotFilter
```

that you can easily override.

Looks like your JwtFilter is not a spring-bean so you can add a constructor param like:

```
new JwtFilter(Set.of(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/logout")))
```

and then just filter requests by overriding shouldNotFilter method to use your  Set of matchers somehow like:

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request) {
    // permittedMatchers == Set.of(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/logout"))
    return permittedMatchers.stream().anyMatch(requestMatcher -> requestMatcher.matches(request));
}
```

and your filter will work only for unmatched routes (routes that are not permitted by default)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same as mentioned in the solution

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
        .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/auth/**").disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("api/content/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("api/auth/signup");
    }
```

Every signup request is still hitting the `doFilterInternal()` method which was is a custom method.

While running `EnableWebSecurity` in debug mode i get :

> Security filter chain:
> [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
> SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
> HeaderWriterFilter
> CorsFilter
> LogoutFilter
> AuthTokenFilter
> RequestCacheAwareFilter
> SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
> AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
> SessionManagementFilter
> ExceptionTranslationFilter
> FilterSecurityInterceptor ]

What should i do to solve this ?

Comment: You can try to implement your JWTFilter as a subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and check if it is included in the SecurityChain. Please take a look at [this](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java) post

Comment: as far as I came to problem you need to do only one thing.                                    
           http
            .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("loginAPI","logoutAPI**")
            .permitAll()  this will help you.