# Spring Security. Bearer Token Validation despite public (permitAll) url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have a security configuration, witch permited some request paths for all. If I send "public" request without Authorization header I can reach application and recive 200 Response. But if I send expired Bearer Authorizaton, Spring try to validate my JWT and I get 401 Error.

Schould Authorization Header not be ignored by "public" url?

My Security Config:

```
    @Bean
@Order(10)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests
                            .requestMatchers(concatArrays(concatArrays(whitelistActuator, new String[]{whitelistError}),
                                    whitelistPublic) )
                            .permitAll().anyRequest()
                            .authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer( oauth2ResourceServer ->
                    oauth2ResourceServer
                            .jwt(jwt ->
                                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter()))
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
            )
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class).authenticationEventPublisher(this.eventPublisher);
    // @formatter:on
    return http.build();
}
```

Spring Security Log:

```
2023-07-28 16:38:53,595 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpConnection: HttpConnection@5a73727b::SocketChannelEndPoint@678cba87[{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:65195,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}]->[HttpConnection@5a73727b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@464c0333{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}] onFillable enter HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} null
2023-07-28 16:38:53,595 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] SocketChannelEndPoint: filled 2476 DirectByteBuffer@180af005[p=0,l=2476,c=8192,r=2476]={<<<HEAD /public/v1/csrf HTTP...4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)\r\n\r\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,595 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-333] SelectableChannelEndPoint: Key interests updated 1 -> 0 on SocketChannelEndPoint@678cba87[{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:65195,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}]->[HttpConnection@5a73727b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@464c0333{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,595 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-333] ManagedSelector: Selector sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@44ba404d waiting with 1 keys
2023-07-28 16:38:53,595 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpConnection: HttpConnection@5a73727b::SocketChannelEndPoint@678cba87[{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:65195,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}]->[HttpConnection@5a73727b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@464c0333{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}] filled 2476 RetainableByteBuffer@5314b5ea{DirectByteBuffer@180af005[p=0,l=2476,c=8192,r=2476]={<<<HEAD /public/v1/csrf HTTP...4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)\r\n\r\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00},r=1}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,595 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpConnection: HttpConnection@5a73727b::SocketChannelEndPoint@678cba87[{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:65195,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}]->[HttpConnection@5a73727b[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@464c0333{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}] parse RetainableByteBuffer@5314b5ea{DirectByteBuffer@180af005[p=0,l=2476,c=8192,r=2476]={<<<HEAD /public/v1/csrf HTTP...4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)\r\n\r\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00},r=1}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: parseNext s=START DirectByteBuffer@180af005[p=0,l=2476,c=8192,r=2476]={<<<HEAD /public/v1/csrf HTTP...4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)\r\n\r\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: START --> SPACE1
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: SPACE1 --> URI
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: URI --> SPACE2
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: SPACE2 --> REQUEST_VERSION
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: REQUEST_VERSION --> HEADER
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Authorization --> VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Authorization --> IN_VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Authorization --> FIELD
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: parsedHeader(null) header=Authorization, headerString=[Authorization], valueString=[Bearer ***]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Host --> VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Host --> IN_VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Host --> FIELD
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: parsedHeader(Host: localhost:8080) header=Host, headerString=[Host], valueString=[localhost:8080]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Connection: keep-alive --> IN_VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:Connection: keep-alive --> FIELD
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: parsedHeader(Connection: keep-alive) header=Connection, headerString=[Connection], valueString=[keep-alive]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:User-Agent --> VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:User-Agent --> IN_VALUE
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER:User-Agent --> FIELD
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: parsedHeader(User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)) header=User-Agent, headerString=[User-Agent], valueString=[Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpParser: HEADER --> CONTENT
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpInput: reopen HttpInput@188787857 cs=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} cp=org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingContentProducer@1dee3d9c eof=false
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] BlockingContentProducer: reopening org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingContentProducer@1dee3d9c
2023-07-28 16:38:53,596 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] AsyncContentProducer: reopening AsyncContentProducer@3a01807d[r=null,t=null,i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpChannel: REQUEST for /public/v1/csrf on HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf,age=1}
HEAD /public/v1/csrf HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ***
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/17.0.5)


2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpConnection: HttpConnection@5a73727b::SocketChannelEndPoint@678cba87[{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:65195,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}]->[HttpConnection@5a73727b[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@464c0333{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf,age=1}] parsed true HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpConnection: releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@5a73727b::SocketChannelEndPoint@678cba87[{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:65195,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}]->[HttpConnection@5a73727b[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@464c0333{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf,age=1}]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpChannel: handle http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf,age=1} 
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpChannelState: handling HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] HttpChannel: action DISPATCH HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf,age=1}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] Server: REQUEST HEAD /public/v1/csrf ?null on HttpChannelOverHttp@75fd70d6{s=HttpChannelState@22cc2c14{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://localhost:8080/public/v1/csrf,age=1}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] ContextHandler: scope null||/public/v1/csrf @ o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@b01cb8d{application,/,[file:///C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.8080.6008215122729850307/, jar:file:/C:/Users/***/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.webjars/swagger-ui/4.18.1/7297bf31fb28c091221409205f9cabdfefd2af52/swagger-ui-4.18.1.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] ContextHandler: context=||/public/v1/csrf @ o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@b01cb8d{application,/,[file:///C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.8080.6008215122729850307/, jar:file:/C:/Users/***/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.webjars/swagger-ui/4.18.1/7297bf31fb28c091221409205f9cabdfefd2af52/swagger-ui-4.18.1.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] SessionHandler: Entering scope org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler952393960==dftMaxIdleSec=1800, dispatch=REQUEST asyncstarted=false
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] SessionHandler: sessionHandler=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler952393960==dftMaxIdleSec=1800 session=null
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] ServletHandler: servlet |/public/v1/csrf|null|ServletPathMapping{matchValue=, pattern=/, servletName=dispatcherServlet, mappingMatch=DEFAULT, servletPath=/public/v1/csrf, pathInfo=null} -> dispatcherServlet==org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet@7ef5559e{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null,STARTED}
2023-07-28 16:38:53,597 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] ServletHandler: chain=Chain@5927b22(org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter==org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter@64757d56{inst=true,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null})->Chain@59d95c6b(characterEncodingFilter==org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter@1d7c9811{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->Chain@4098593c(webMvcObservationFilter==org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter@3ce7394f{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->Chain@30731804(formContentFilter==org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter@6723cce7{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->Chain@26ae3e43(requestContextFilter==org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter@74cd798f{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->Chain@350714f9(springSecurityFilterChain==org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1@7f012923{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->Chain@37d4fadc(jwtCsrfTokenFilter==de.myfir.maklerportal.security.csrf.JwtCsrfTokenFilter@601f264d{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->Chain@1fcf671a(resourceFilter==de.myfir.maklerportal.security.emabac.ResourceFilter@4403bff8{inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null})->ChainEnd@48441e86(dispatcherServlet==org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet@7ef5559e{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=true,async=true,src=JAKARTA_API:null,STARTED})
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@220cda54, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@39109603, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1e5e3147, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@44dcc0e4, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4d3990a5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@43f7f48d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@2c3b0cc8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3aed692d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@74cd8c55, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@18df26a1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6cd6698b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@fe38c0e]] (1/3)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Securing HEAD /public/v1/csrf
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking CorsFilter (5/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 DEBUG [qtp1542747725-39] RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped to de.myfir.bff.mi.CsrfRestController#getCsrf()
2023-07-28 16:38:53,598 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,599 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] LogoutFilter: Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-07-28 16:38:53,599 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] FilterChainProxy: Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2023-07-28 16:38:53,599 TRACE [qtp1542747725-39] ProviderManager: Authenticating request with JwtAuthenticationProvider (1/2)

*** and hier will be error Token validation
```

Comment: please enable spring security DEBUG or TRACE logs and update your question with the full logs so that we can see what is actually happening under the hood.

Comment: I will add log, but it's not very helpful. You can see that my JWT is not valid and it's true, but my Question is why JWT is actually validated.

Comment: i dont know if i was unclear i asked for the full logs you have cut out all the actual relevant information before the exception so that we can actually see what the server is doing before the exception. Thats why i wrote the FULL logs, and not "the exception"

Comment: It was full log with DEBUG. With TRACE is comming more

Comment: why do you have this `@Order(10)`? there is something here you arnt telling us

Comment: Because it's giving more Filters :) . I think I got it. If I start without Autorization Header I got:
 2023-07-28 16:53:28,337 TRACE [qtp1542747725-42] BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter: Did not process request since did not find bearer token

Comment: also what is this `concatArrays(whitelistActuator, new String[]{whitelistError}`

Comment: it is very hard for us to help you when there is a lot of abstraction and things that are not needed for the problem in the code example. We cant reproduce things or rule out things if there a lot of things ntd needed in the example as clutter

Comment: It's mean that BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter is active undependent of my url, but if Bearer Header is not available - it makes no validation

Comment: Sorry I tried to remove most of unrelated code

Comment: for instance, how do i know if the problem is not in this code? `concatArrays(whitelistActuator, new String[]{whitelistError}` you are posting here `/public/v1/csrf` i cant see anywhere in your code that you have whitelisted this endpoint?

Comment: I am very apreciated you for your help. Your suggestion set spring security on trace was very helpful

Comment: This thread is also very helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896502/spring-security-bypass-url-or-filter

Comment: And for spring-boot 3
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityCustomizer.html#customize(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)